How to retrieve the height of a document ready to be printed, the one in relation with the `media='print'` css file?
I have set a different css file for printing, to I have two css files:
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='basics.css'> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='print' href='print.css'> 

I'm trying to set a printing with page numbers, so before printing, I calculate what is the height of the page, and I count how many pages do I have to print.
But the problem is that the height which is calculated is based upon the media='screen' one, invoking the property:
document.body.scrollHeight

I would like to get this value from the real ready-to-print page, the one which is bigger than the displayed page, because it has some page breaks, so that the printed pdf is often bigger than the latter.
How is it possible to retrieve the new height of the page ready to be printed, the one which have the media='print' css file ?

To get the rendered depth of the document in pixels, use...
document.documentElement.scrollHeight

As for getting info from the "ready-to-print" dialog page, I've never heard of it returning any values... it's the programmer that can pass values to it before initiating the print job.
I'll give you some basic instructions for setting up printing in case you don't already know, but there's lots more you can do so you'll have to research the matter...
@page {

 margin: 0 auto; // Eliminates header/footer

 size: A4 portrait; // portrait|landscape|A4|A3|letter|A4 landscape|10cm|420px|6in|640px 360px|20cm 15cm|auto

 page-orientation: upright;  // upright|rotate-left|rotate-right

}


The method document.documentElement.scrollHeight return only 100px more than  document.body.scrollHeight does, eventthough it should much more than that, because there is enlargement of images and page breaks...
I used to use even recently this: content: counter(page);
But it is not maintained...
